# lastname, telephone fields as optional in onepage checkout shipping address

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-address, customer-attribute

I would like to make lastname, telephone, zipcode and city as optional field in billing address column since our site is internal. So created a mysql script and changed the version in config file. After clearing the cache I loaded the page. In `eav_attribute` table those fields are updated as non required field, but still I am getting the validation message as attached.

[image]

Whats the wrong with this?

mysql upgrade script:

```
<?php
    $installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();
/*** Update customer address attributes*/
$installer->updateAttribute('customer_address', 'lastname', 'is_required', 0);
$installer->updateAttribute('customer_address', 'telephone', 'is_required', 0);
$installer->updateAttribute('customer_address', 'city', 'is_required', 0);
$installer->updateAttribute('customer_address', 'postcode', 'is_required', 0);

$installer->endSetup();
?>
```

Comment: @SanderMangel I read the link. I I change in abstract.php wont it affect other areas?

Comment: postcode is used for shipping calculations and make it optional will probably cause a whole list of errors and issues. You might want to rethink removing it as required

Comment: Yes it will also in the customer section of Magento where you add your address

Comment: @SanderMangel If I modify in Mage/Customer/Model/Address/Abstract.php. directly wont it affect if I upgrade my magento version, I read from blog that we should not modify the core code

Comment: No I agree, you're absolutely right. But this is currently the only place where it can be removed. I might have a work around, give me a sec

Comment: @SanderMangel Sure, thanks for your effort and quick response

Comment: Ok, you could create an observer that dispatches on `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_saveShipping` which checks values in the post. If telephone or city etc is empty fill it with something default like a dash (-)

Comment: @SanderMangel thats good idea. But Magento will check only not empty validation? In that case in sales->orders under address section that '-' or '*' will be displayed right?

Comment: Not sure, that would be something you could try out

Comment: @SanderMangel I just filled with '***' and its working fine. Thanks..